# validation touched event is not working with angular 5.2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have one input type like:

```
<input type="text" name="emaill" #emaill="ngModel" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)@\w+([\.-]?\w+)(\.\w{2,3})+$" [(ngModel)]="user.email" class="form-control input-underline" required />

<div *ngIf="(emaill.invalid && emaill.touched) || (emaill.touched && emaill.pristine)" class="error-block">
        <div [hidden]="!emaill.errors.required">Enter email</div>
        <div [hidden]="!emaill.errors.pattern">Invalid email</div>
       </div>
```

but it seems like touched event is not working, the same event was working before with `angular 4.3`.But after switch to `angular 5` the touched event is always be false.when i print like `{{emaill.touched}}` it is always be false even after touch the input type.
Also if i change my input type "text" to "password",it is working fine .

Comment: It will be true when the input loses the focus

Comment: yeah,but it will not changing to true.But for input type "password" it is changing to true.

Comment: It needs to have a change on modl to 'touched' be true.

Comment: can you please elaborate,i am still stuck on it.And why it is working when i change to  input type="password"?

Answer (score 0):

The error triggered by not exiting yet "emaill.error" blocks the value. Check the console and you will see.

Change for this:

```
   ...
   <div [hidden]="!emaill.errors?.required">Enter email</div>
   <div [hidden]="!emaill.errors?.pattern">Invalid email</div>
   ...
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o2vvvq)

Comment: its not working for me.Also nothing error message in console.

Comment: In my demo click on the second input and then check the console

Comment: I checked in your demo but this {{emaill.touched}} is always false.

Comment: Ok, first click on the first input and then click on the second

Comment: yeah it is working in your demo.But the same is not working in my code :(

Comment: Have you made the change with "?" ?

Comment: is there is any version issue with angular? because i am using angular 5.2.1 and in your demo it is angular 5.0.0.?

Comment: Ohh thanks,but not work in my case. After tried many times what i have done is to send the value of name parameter on blur to components.And update its touched event to true in service  :)